# Stuck in "half-installed" state with Texlive-full, not enough disk space

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm using an AWS free tier server with 8GB of space. I tried installing Texlive-full, but ran out of space before installation completed. I then tried running:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove texlive-full
```

But I received an error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zathura-pdf-poppler : Depends: zathura-abi-2gtk3
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So, I next ran

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The result of this is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1020 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1022 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1026 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1028
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1030 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1031 linux-headers-4.4.0-1020-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1022-aws
  linux-headers-4.4.0-1026-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1028-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1030-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1031-aws
  linux-image-4.4.0-1020-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1022-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1026-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1028-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1030-aws
  linux-image-4.4.0-1031-aws
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed: 
  texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-games texlive-generic-extra texlive-htmlxml texlive-humanities
  texlive-humanities-doc texlive-lang-african texlive-lang-arabic texlive-lang-chinese texlive-lang-cjk texlive-lang-cyrillic
  texlive-lang-czechslovak texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european texlive-lang-french texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-greek
  texlive-lang-indic texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-japanese texlive-lang-korean texlive-lang-polish texlive-lang-portuguese
  texlive-lang-spanish texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-luatex texlive-math-extra texlive-metapost-doc texlive-music texlive-omega
  texlive-plain-extra texlive-publishers texlive-publishers-doc texlive-science texlive-science-doc zathura
Suggested packages:
  www-browser zathura-ps zathura-djvu zathura-cb
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-games texlive-generic-extra texlive-htmlxml texlive-humanities
  texlive-humanities-doc texlive-lang-african texlive-lang-arabic texlive-lang-chinese texlive-lang-cjk texlive-lang-cyrillic
  texlive-lang-czechslovak texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european texlive-lang-french texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-greek
  texlive-lang-indic texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-japanese texlive-lang-korean texlive-lang-polish texlive-lang-portuguese
  texlive-lang-spanish texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-luatex texlive-math-extra texlive-metapost-doc texlive-music texlive-omega
  texlive-plain-extra texlive-publishers texlive-publishers-doc texlive-science texlive-science-doc zathura
0 upgraded, 37 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,281 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,436 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

The problem at this point is that I don't have enough space to continue...I'm about 600MB short. I could probably pay AWS to enlarge the storage space, at least temporarily, but I'd rather not do that.

I've tried freeing up space by running apt-get clean, apt-get autoclean, etc. but it doesn't free up enough space.

So, things are in a "half-installed" state and I can't go forward or backward.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: try `sudo apt-get -f remove`. This will attempt to remove packets.  You can additionally list what to remove.

Comment: I tried this...this also wants to install new packages, requiring 1.8GB of additional space. I only have 1.2 GB available...